# CMV Pass Dynamic Lat Long to URL

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I have created a Reporting services report which has custom urls for  my CMV viewer based on the lat long for the feature in the record. I would like to click on it and open my CMV app a the custom Lat/Long and zoom level. Is that possible.

Here is an example:

http:///CMVApp/#/-122.71970/38.54753/19

The -122.71970/38.54753/19 would be what would change each time. I've tried this and sometimes it will zoom to the right location and other times it goes to the center of my map extent.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  It's hard for a potential answerer to know why things aren't working if you haven't shown what you've actually tried.  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of any code and details of the settings/configuration you've used that produces the undesired result.